# cakephp 2.x how to save data in habtm join table only?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a users and a posts table.
When I save the post it successfully saves it through HABTM (in posts_users table as well).

Now I want that post to be accessible to multiple user.
How can I add data in `posts_users` table alone so that `post_id` is now also associated with other `user_id` in the table `users_posts` ?

I have tried the following code:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('User.id',array('value'=>34));
echo $this->Form->input('Post.id',array('value'=>34));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the unique HABTM key:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Post' => array(
        'className' => 'Post',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'post_id',
        'joinTable' => 'posts_users',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    )
);
```